# Changing SVG's gradient using JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, gradient

I'm trying to change the stop color of a gradient in the following SVG element, by attempting to change the `stop-color` attribute, but it does not work:

```html
<svg><defs> 
<linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
<stop offset="40%" stop-color="purple" id="firstGradient"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" id="secondGradient"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<Here's a long line of picture>
</svg>
```

I am using the following script statement to attempt to change the stop color:

```js
document.getElementById("firstGradient").stopColor ="red";
```

I also have tried `document.getElementById("firstGradient").attr.stop-color = "red";`.

Neither approaches work. How do I change the stop color?

Comment: What is `<Here's a long line of picture>`, exactly? That syntax is invalid, put some valid content there, please -- we can't read your thoughts on what exactly the gradient is for (changing gradient is reflected on some content, not on the gradient alone so saying "nothing works" is pretty much unverifiable without the content your question omits).

Comment: By the way, what is `stopColor` property? Where did you hear about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it with:

```
document.getElementById("firstGradient").style.stopColor ="red";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I have no clue why I didn’t try to do it through “style”. Its  working.  
However, I still don’t understand why is this construction works, after all there’s style named “stop-color” but not “stopColor”. Do you know why is it works and why is typing “style.stop-color” won’t be correct?

Comment: Because of Consistency you should use camelCase instead of kebab-case

Comment: It has nothing to do with consistency, it has to do with how prevalent standards specifications [mandate it behave](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface). It's all specified further down in section 5.6.1.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you're making is assuming -- I am not sure what resource(s) you use for reference -- is that there is defined a `stopColor` property on whatever object `document.getElementByid("firstGradient")` returns. There isn't.

The element you call "firstGradient" is an [`SVGStopElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#InterfaceSVGStopElement) and as you can see from the specification, it doesn't provide any `stopColor` property.

But no cause for distress -- by changing the actual element attribute you are changing the stop color, that's how the Document Object Model works -- you don't need to use any special properties of the element at all to change the actual attribute:

```js
document.getElementById("firstGradient").setAttribute("stop-color", "red");
```

That's all. `setAttribute` function is available for any document element, SVG, HTML or any other namespace/kind.

By the way, I wouldn't refer to stop colors as gradients -- calling the element you're calling "firstGradient" is simply misleading -- it's a *stop color* not a *gradient*, the gradient is the actual `linearGradient` element. So if you want to assign identifiers, assign "gradientFirstStopColor" and "gradientSecondStopColor" to the first and second `stop` elements, respectively, if anything.

But you might as well just identify the stop color elements using their order in the child hierarchy:

```js
document.querySelector("linearGradient > stop:nth-of-type(1)").setAttribute("stop-color", "red");
```

You can use other CSS selectors or APIs (e.g. `querySelectorAll("linearGradient > stop")[1]`), my point is you don't have to absolutely resort to assigning identifiers, although it helps in certain situations -- they absolutely have their legitimate uses.

Of course using the `style` property on the stop element also works, but I personally think the semantics of having `style` on a non-rendered (gradients aren't rendered themselves) element, is bonkers -- it's a leaking abstraction, basically.

Answer (score 1):

It is 2022, we have native JavaScript Web Components

Wrap your `<svg>` in a `<svg-gradient>` Onload it will read the defined `GRAD` color array and **create** the `<stop >` values in your `<svg>`

Note the **3** places where you define and use `GRAD`; this allows for multiple gradients within your `<svg>`

```html
<svg-gradient GRAD="red,red,red,red,red,red,#f8991d,#ffe400,#51ff00,#0066ae,#1b449c,#792b87">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="GRAD"></linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle r="255" cx="256" cy="256" fill="url(#GRAD)" />
  </svg>
</svg-gradient>


<script>
  customElements.define("svg-gradient", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure innerHTML was parsed
        this.querySelectorAll("linearGradient")
          .forEach(gradient => {
            gradient.innerHTML =
              this
              .getAttribute(gradient.id)
              .split(",")
              .map((color, idx, colors) => 
                 `<stop offset="${idx*1/colors.length}" stop-color="${color}"/>`)
              .join("")
          });
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```